# href to a variable url section - Angular + Bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, href

I am following one of the `bootstrap`'s template and I am dealing with the next problem:

**Template**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
  <a class="portfolio-box" href="img/portfolio/fullsize/1.jpg">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
      <div class="project-category text-white-50">
        Category
      </div>
      <div class="project-name">
        Project Name
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

My problem is the following:

```
`href` in the `<a>` seems to shows in a modal the image in a bigger size, but I am trying to use it as a variable.
```

I have tried to use `ng-ref="myvariable"` but it does not happen (either an error)

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do the next:

```
...


    <a class="portfolio-box" href={{ your-variable}}>

...
```

Value of "your-variable" should be in the component of this template.